# How do I do this query in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

We have a json column 'passed_states_data' in table party_procedures

The column data looks like this:

> [{"state":"documents","passed_at":"2016-02-04 13:16:51
>   +0100"},{"state":"problems","passed_at":"2016-02-04 16:10:07 +0100"},{"state":"waiting_for_physical_documents","passed_at":"2016-02-08
>   13:50:17
>   +0100"},{"state":"customer_acceptance","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:50:19
>   +0100"},{"state":"customer_identifier","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:50:54 +0100"},{"state":"checking_account","passed_at":"2016-02-08
>   13:51:45
>   +0100"},{"state":"transfer_money_to_savings_account","passed_at":"2016-02-10
>   09:12:18 +0100"}]

I need to build query that only returns rows where 'transfer_money_to_savings_account' exists and then get the passed_at date.

so the query should return something like this:

```
select blah as "date passed" from party_procedures pp
  where json_array_elements(pp.passed_states_data)->>'state'='transfer_money_to_savings_account' = 't'
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`json_array_elements()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) function returns *set of json*, therefore, you cannot use `->>` for that; in other words, you need to iterate over the set of json array elements and check if `state` has a value you a looking for.

```
WITH t(passed_states_data) AS ( VALUES
  ('[{"state":"documents","passed_at":"2016-02-04 13:16:51 +0100"},
     {"state":"problems","passed_at":"2016-02-04 16:10:07 +0100"},
     {"state":"waiting_for_physical_documents","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:50:17 +0100"},
     {"state":"customer_acceptance","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:50:19 +0100"},
     {"state":"customer_identifier","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:50:54 +0100"},
     {"state":"checking_account","passed_at":"2016-02-08 13:51:45 +0100"},
     {"state":"transfer_money_to_savings_account","passed_at":"2016-02-10 09:12:18 +0100"}]'::JSON)
)
SELECT j->>'passed_at' as "date passed" FROM t, json_array_elements(t.passed_states_data) j
WHERE j->>'state' = 'transfer_money_to_savings_account';
```

Result:

```
        date passed        
---------------------------
 2016-02-10 09:12:18 +0100
(1 row)
```